# How to loop a JOptionsPane

Tags: java, loops, joptionpane

Alright well, I semi figured it out with some searching, but now I have another issue
When the second box pops up and I click 'no' the first box still runs and if I cancel it I get an error.  What am I doing wrong?

```
  import javax.swing.*;
 import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RPS {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    String input;                      
    int user;                       
    int computer;                   
while (true){//here we go
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What'll it be? Rock, paper, or scissors?\n" +
                "1 for rock, 2 for paper, and 3 for scissors: ",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);


    user = Integer.parseInt(input);


    Random randomnum = new Random ();

    computer = randomnum.nextInt(3);




    if (user == 1 && computer == 0){System.out.println ("You played Rock! You have tied");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie!");}

    else if (user == 1 && computer == 1){System.out.println ("You have played Rock! You have lost");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Paper beats rock. You lose!");}

    else if (user == 1 && computer == 2){System.out.println ("You have played Rock! You have won");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rock beats scissors. You win!");}

    else if (user == 2 && computer == 0){System.out.println ("You have played Paper! You have won");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Paper beats rock. You win!");}

    else if (user == 2 && computer == 1){System.out.println ("You have played Paper! You have tied");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie!");}

    else if (user == 2 && computer == 2){System.out.println ("You have played Paper! You have lost");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Scissors beats paper. You lose!");}

    else if (user == 3 && computer == 0){System.out.println ("You have played Scissors! You have lost");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rock beats Scissors. You lose!");}

    else if (user == 3 && computer == 1){System.out.println ("You have played Scissors! You have won");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Scissors beats paper. You win!");}

    else if (user == 3 && computer == 2){System.out.println ("You have played Scissors! You have tied");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie!");}



     int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Would you like to play again?", "Confirmation",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
       if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Let's start");
       } else {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Goodbye");
       } 

  }
 }
}
```

Comment: show your code. please

Comment: Please post your code and what you have tried (if anything). Everything is possible, it's just a matter of proper programming.

Comment: Have you learned about `while` loops yet?

Comment: @peeskillet I have and I've tried that but I think I might be doing them incorrectly. It loops infinitely when I use while loops even if I break. I may be doing it in an incorrect place however.

Comment: I don't see your attempt at the `while` loop

Comment: I got rid of it because it wasn't working. @peeskillet

Comment: @peeskillet I'm sorry I'm not quite clear as to what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `return;` statement after `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Goodbye");`. otherwise it doesn't know to end the while loop.

The error when you press cancel would happen also if you chose cancel right away. It's because parseInt doesn't know how to read the resulting input. You should check the return value of showInputDialog to see that it's valid output. I would suggest checking for "1", "2", or "3" (or "rock", "paper", or "scizzors") instead of using parseInt, and then if it doesn't match any of them to come up with an error message of some sort.